# Simple cURL via Applescript / Shell

Tags: macos, curl, applescript

I want to send a simple cUrl in Applescript/shell

```
URL: http://10.0.1.14/api/newdeveloper/lights/2/state
Boddy: {"on":false}
Method: Put
```

Anyone can maybe help maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all the below lines into a single one, and then execute.

```
curl -X PUT 
  -d "{\"on\":false}"
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  "http://10.0.1.14/api/newdeveloper/lights/2/state"
```